# Macbook Pro SSD dying?

Tags: ssd, macbook-pro

My Macbook pro retina (2012 model) with a 256Gb SSD has been showing some worrying signs.

I fear the SSD might be worn out.

This computer has been used almost day for the past 2 years for intensive coding and UI design work.

Here are the signs:

- 1 app reports there is no disk space to write files to while there is 20Gb left
- I have had to run disk repair to repair bad sectors on the drive, but have been warned by a colleague that disk repair is evil for SSDs (I wonder why Apple allows you to do it then)
- Some apps have trouble writing to temporary disk locations (I get i/o write errors in After Effects)
- General slowness and having to reboot the computer because things just get too slow (I blamed Yosemite for this)

Does anyone have any advice? I have multiple backups and online backups, and I already ordered 1 new 1Tb SSD to replace it, but I wonder what is going on. I am expecting a top of the line $3000 computer to work for at least a few years, but this seems to be a false hope.

(P.S. I didn't attempt a full clean reinstall yet)

Comment: Still under warranty? And does the hard drive manufacturer have any diagnostic tools, like SMART tools for regular hard drives?

Comment: `brew` contains smartmontools. With my rMBP Late '13 I can check the SSD SMART status (`sudo /usr/local/sbin/smartctl -a /dev/disk0`), and `smartctl` even claims to know the device.

Comment: Here is some diagnostic data from the above command: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Wolfr/25942688f1f7312897ae/raw/9aa5e81e4deeb04b2fe82d9635eb5fa9ec54bb0e/gistfile1.txt

(unfortunately the warranty just expired last month)